# How Add List of objects to XSD properly

Tags: java, xsd

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Consents">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Marketing" type="ConsentType" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="CheckExternalDB" type="ConsentType" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DocsByEMail" type="ConsentType" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DocsByPrintHouse" type="ConsentType" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DocsByEBOK" type="ConsentType" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DataToGroup" type="TimeConsentType" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="MarketingGroup" type="TimeConsentType" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="EMarketingInf" type="TimeConsentType" />
              <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                 <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CustomerConsents" type="CustomerConsentsBasic" />
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
```

My class looks like this

```
public class CompanyType {  
    @XmlElement(name = "Consents")
    protected CompanyType.Consents consents;
}

  public static class Consents { 
        @XmlElement(name = "CustomerConsents")
        protected List<CustomerConsentsBasic> customerConsents;
 }
```

customerConsents is a list and I want to represent this correctly. Above is my XSD, could someone correct it if its wrong somewhere.